# MVC app .xlsx file downloading as type file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel

I'm working on an MVC application and trying to link to an Excel file on a file share that our users can download.  I thought I had it set up correctly, but when I download the file it comes back as type 'file'.

UI Code

```
@Html.ActionLink("Excel sheet", "Download", new { @class = "a" })
```

Controller Code

```
public FileResult Download()
    {
        var FilePath = CurrentSettings.FilePath + "Template Files\\Entry Template.xlsx";

        return File(FilePath, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml", "Specimen Template File");
    }
```

and here's how it shows up in Windows Explorer.

[image]

Feel like this is something obvious, hoping someone else has run into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the `File` method you are using is:

```
FilePathResult File(string fileName, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
```

As you can see, the last parameter is file download name. So you need to provide the name of the file, *including the extension*.

```
return File(FilePath,
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet.main+xml",
  "Specimen Template File.xlsx");
```

Comment: Wow, man.  Thought it would be obvious, just not embarrassingly obvious.

Thanks dude, was one of the last things I needed to do before taking off for the week.  Have a great Thanksgiving.